# MySQL WEEK() mode 6 PHP equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I want to use YEARWEEK to aggregate data on weekly basis, and I want Sunday as first day of the week. In SQL query I use mode 6 to aggregate data, but don't have yearweek equivalent in PHP. PHP it seems don't have option for changing week starting day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution so far

```
public static function getYearWeek(DateTime $dateTime)
    {
        $minDaysInWeek = 4;
        $numDaysInWeek = 7;
        $firstDayOfYear = clone $dateTime;
        $lastDayOfYear = clone $dateTime;
        $yearStartingDay = $firstDayOfYear->modify('first day of January this year')->format('N');
        $numberOfDaysInYear = $lastDayOfYear->modify('last day of December this year')->format('z') + 1;
        $ordinalDate = $dateTime->format('z') + 1;
        $weekOffset = $yearStartingDay < $minDaysInWeek ? 1 : 0;

        $weekNum = ceil(($ordinalDate + $yearStartingDay - $numDaysInWeek) / $numDaysInWeek) + $weekOffset;
        $maxWeekNum = ceil(($numberOfDaysInYear + $yearStartingDay - $numDaysInWeek) / $numDaysInWeek) + $weekOffset;

        if($weekNum < 1) {
            return self::getYearWeek(clone $dateTime->modify('last day of December previous year'));
        }

        if($weekNum > $maxWeekNum) {
            return self::getYearWeek(clone $dateTime->modify('first day of January next year'));
        }

        return intval($dateTime->format('Y') . ($weekNum < 9 ? '0' . $weekNum : $weekNum));
    }
```

Does anyone has some better solution?